# Name of this symmetric polytope

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-geometry, polytopes

I am a theoretical computer science student who is not well versed in convex geometry, so could someone point me to the correct name of the following type of convex polytopes (if they are named)?

A convex polytope $P$ which is symmetric with respect to $S_n$ group action. Formally, let $\bar{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector. Then, $\bar{v} \in P$ if and only if $\sigma\circ \bar{v} \in P$, for every $\sigma \in S_n$, where $S_n$ is the finite symmetric group. Here, $\sigma\circ \bar{v}$ represents a permutation of the original vector $\bar{v}$.

Comment: I don't think these are likely to be named. They describe a *lot* of polytopes; in the case $n=3$, it describes any convex polytope with $3$-fold symmetry. It's also not quite a property of a polytope, since your definition further stipulates a particular position in space and isn't invariant under movements of the polytope.

Comment: Do you assume that there is only one orbit of vertices w.r.t. $S_n$? And do you use the standard action of the symmetric group on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ resp. its irreducible component on $\Bbb R^n$, or do you consider also other actions?

Comment: @M.Winter, Sorry I did not understand your question. Actually, I'm working with integral vectors, i.e. $\bar{v} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Moreover, all the vectors are $n$-dimensional only. All I'm saying is that if a vector is in polytope, then all the distinct permutations of this vector must also be present. This is the only condition required to be satisfied. For example, if $(1,1,2) \in P$, then $(1,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1)$ must also be present. Here $n=3$.

Comment: @PranavBisht Are you aware of the notion of a [permutahedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron)? It is not exactly what you want (it has a single orbit of vertices), but each of your polytopes is the convex hull of several permutahedra.